# how to deal with action bar's button listners

Tags: android

I am new to android and dont know where should i write the actionlistner code for action bar buttons so that i don't need to write the action listner code in all activity.

Please look at below image: i have a menu.xml file for action bar menu and added in one of my activity via onCreateOptionMenu function. when user click on any of my button of action bar then i can track it via onOptionItemSelected function.

Problem-1: For all other activity, i can use same menu.xml file but do i need to override onCreateOptionMenu function of each activity.

Problem 2: Do i need to write onOptionItemSelected function code in all activity?

Please suggest me better solution of these problems.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Problem-1: For all other activity, i can use same menu.xml file but do i need to override onCreateOptionMenu function of each activity.
>
> Problem 2: Do i need to write onOptionItemSelected function code in all activity?

You can create a 'base' `Activity` and implement the methods in that. Then all you need to do is make sure all other `Activities` extend the 'base' `Activity`.

Example (note I use ActionBarSherlock so my 'base' `Activity` initially extends `ShelockFragmentActivity` - that may not be the same in your case but this gives an example)...

```
public class MyBaseFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        // Handle menu selection here
    }
}
```

Now any `Activity` that extends that 'base' `Activity` will automatically inherit the menu creation and item selection methods of the 'base' class.

```
public class ActivityA extends MyBaseFragmentActivity {

    // No need to create the menu or handle item selection

}
```

Comment: I think, this is good solution. I will try to integrate it. Thanks for providing solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem-1: For all other activity, i can use same menu.xml file but do i need to override onCreateOptionMenu function of each activity.

Yes, simply add your code to handle the menu options in a switch statement.

> Problem 2: Do i need to write onOptionItemSelected function code in all activity?

Yes, for each activity that is using the action bar, you will need to override the onOptionItemSelected function and add your custom code.

For example:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_watchlist:
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, WatchlistActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", currentUser.getUsername());
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_history:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class);
            intent2.putExtra("username", currentUser.getUsername());
            startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_scores:
            // Scores only available with Facebook login
            if (facebookLogin)
            {
                Intent scoreIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ScoresActivity.class);
                scoreIntent.putExtra("username",  currentUser.getUsername());
                scoreIntent.putExtra("accessToken",  accessToken);
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                scoreIntent.putExtra("session", session);
                startActivityForResult(scoreIntent, 0);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please login to Facebook to use this feature.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            intent3.putExtra("username", currentUser.getUsername());
            startActivityForResult(intent3, 0);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: But in my project i have more then 20 activity and all are using same action bar so it will be wastage of time to write same code again and again. Please suggest me some other way. If possible..

Comment: I would copy and paste... would only take a minute or two to add to 20 activities (which seems like A LOT for an app).  You could put the switch statement in a separate class, but you'd still need to override the onOptionItemSelected to give the action bar functionality.

Comment: But after pasting this code at all place, if i want to change a small thing in my code then again i need to change in all places!!

Comment: Then put the switch statement in a separate class... just call the function in the onOptionItemSelected and then return true.  You can go in your class and make the changes just once.